# How to clear a TextBox so that the default Undo method still functions?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've been looking for a while now and haven't found an easy or correct way to solve the following issue.

I have a multi-line TextBox with the `ShortcutsEnabled = true` which, of course, allows the user to easily undo or redo any changes made by using the keyboard shortcuts (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>).
Now I wish to implement a button that clears the text of the TextBox but still allow the user to undo the action by using the default undo function.

Clearing the text from the TextBox is easy:

```
myTextBox.Clear();  
//or 
myTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
```

The problem is that the default undo function does not work when replacing the text these ways.
However, if the user selects all the text ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> ) and hits <kbd>Delete</kbd> manually, the TextBox becomes empty and the user can still restore the deleted data by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.

I know that writing my own implementation of `Undo` or `Redo` would probably allow me to get the desired result but there has to be another way.
I simply need to be ably to mimic the manual select all and delete method in code.

And this is where I need some help, how can I implement this?

TextBox doesn't seem to have a default *Delete*, *Remove* or *Replace* text function that I can call.
As a proof of concept I've tried implementing this using the `Cut` method (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> ) , which actually does what I want. The only downside is that this replaces potentially important clipboard data. I've tried coming up with a workaround for this as well, but after doing some research there doesn't seem to be any "correct" or at least "great" way to restore clipboard data.

```
var cbData = Clipboard.GetText();
myTextBox.SelectAll();
myTextBox.Cut();
Clipboard.Clear();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbData))
     Clipboard.SetText(cbData);
```

---

**TLDR;**

How can I delete the text from a TextBox in code the same way a user would do manually? So that the default `Undo` method can still be called to restore the deleted text?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about focusing the TextBox, selecting all text and then simulating a backspace? It's the same as the user manually clearing the TextBox. (Atleast, I clear text fields in this way)

```
textBox1.Focus();
textBox1.SelectAll();
SendKeys.Send("{BACKSPACE}");
```

---

A bit of partially relevant **fact** - In WPF, no matter how you change the text, the *Undo* and *Redo* methods always function properly.

Comment: As rational behind this, a quote from MSDN: _An application can reset an edit control's undo flag by sending the control an EM_EMPTYUNDOBUFFER message. The system automatically resets the undo flag whenever an edit control receives an EM_SETHANDLE or WM_SETTEXT message. The SetDlgItemText function sends a WM_SETTEXT message._

Comment: I knew how to do the select all part but I didn't know how to simulate/mimic a delete or backspace. So you've definitely helped me already. I'll leave the question open just a little longer to see if anyone else can come up with an even better approach. It baffles me that there isn't any clean way to do this.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, could you please link your source?

Comment: @Oceans yes, this MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775460(v=vs.85).aspx#undoing_operations. Pretty weird (IMO) but that's it. I think Fᴀʀʜᴀɴ Aɴᴀᴍ works pretty well (don't forget to also check with other IME or you may have surprises in production).

Comment: Since Undo and Redo are handled by the browser, it seems like results might vary depending on the browser.  In fact, while testing out a client-side only solution to this problem, I think I have discovered a bug in Chrome's Undo/Redo handling that does not occur in IE. https://www.lanitek.com/ltek/textBoxClear.html I used Chrome's "Report an issue..." to report it.

Comment: @EricBarr this is WinForms, not WebForms.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ Ahhh, sorry :-/  Interesting in web context too though :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a bit hackish method, ask MS why such methods are not public.

```
public static class TextBoxUtils
{
    // internal virtual void SetSelectedTextInternal(string text, bool clearUndo)
    private static readonly Action<TextBox, string, bool> SetSelectedTextInternal =
        (Action<TextBox, string, bool>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TextBox, string, bool>),
        typeof(TextBox).GetMethod("SetSelectedTextInternal", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic));

    public static void UndoableClear(this TextBox target)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(target.Text)) return;
        target.SelectAll();
        SetSelectedTextInternal(target, string.Empty, false);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
myTextBox.UndoableClear();
```

If you don't like hacks, you can use P/Invoke and send [EM_REPLACESEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761633(v=vs.85).aspx) message which does not clear text editor internal undo buffer like `WM_SETTEXT`.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question as I was searching for a solution in VB.net. 
Ivan's "hackish" solution works just fine in VB.

As vb.net:

```
Module Module1
    Private ReadOnly SetSelectedTextInternal As Action(Of TextBox, String, Boolean) =
        DirectCast([Delegate].CreateDelegate(GetType(Action(Of TextBox, String, Boolean)),
                                         GetType(TextBox).GetMethod("SetSelectedTextInternal",
                                         BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)),
                                         Action(Of TextBox, String, Boolean))
    <Extension>
    Public Sub Delete(target As TextBox)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(target.Text) Then Return
        'target.SelectAll()
        SetSelectedTextInternal(target, String.Empty, False)
    End Sub
End Module
```