# undo/redo with protected text in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf, undo-redo

we are using RichTextBox to display text. we are having issues to undo/redo with protected text.

here's the workflow, normally we have pure text and in this case undo/redo works perfectly. occasionally we need to mark certain text to be "Protected". we do the validation and convert the Rtf on the fly and do the following to assign it back to the RTB:

```
m_rtbText.Rtf = sRtf
```

the problem is after step over this line, the

```
m_rtbText.CanUndo
```

property will be set to False internally, as a result we lost all the undo steps. To give you an example, here is what it looks like before the validation:

```
\cf1\i0\v\f2 <PSI_START_OBJECT><PSI_MEDIA><Media2><MediaID>16346</MediaID><Name>\f3\rtlch\'e4\'d4\'d1\'c9 \'cc\'e6\'ed\'c9</\f2\ltrch Name><FileName>N:\\media\f3\rtlch\\\'e4\'d4\'d1\'c9 \'cc\'e6\'ed\'c9_1.\f2\ltrch wav</FileName><Length>00:00:33.0</Length><OutCue></OutCue><Description></Description></Media2><PSI_MID_OBJECT\f3\rtlch >\v0\f0\'c7\'e1\'ca\'de\'d1\'ed\'d1 \'c7\'e1\'c5\'ce\'c8\'c7\'d1\'ed : \cf2\'e4\'d4\'d1\'c9 \'cc\'e6\'ed\'c9\par
 \cf1\'c7\'e1\'e3\'cf\'f8\'c9 : \cf2\f3 00:00:33.0\cf3\i\f4 .\v <\f1\ltrch PSI_END_OBJECT\f4\rtlch >\cf0\v0\f1\ltrch\par
```

and here's what looks like after the validation:

```
\cf1\i0\protect\v\f2 <PSI_START_OBJECT><PSI_MEDIA><Media2><MediaID>16346</MediaID><Name>\f3\rtlch\'e4\'d4\'d1\'c9 \'cc\'e6\'ed\'c9</\f2\ltrch Name><FileName>N:\\media\f3\rtlch\\\'e4\'d4\'d1\'c9 \'cc\'e6\'ed\'c9_1.\f2\ltrch wav</FileName><Length>00:00:33.0</Length><OutCue></OutCue><Description></Description></Media2><PSI_MID_OBJECT\f3\rtlch >\v0\f0\'c7\'e1\'ca\'de\'d1\'ed\'d1 \'c7\'e1\'c5\'ce\'c8\'c7\'d1\'ed : \cf2\'e4\'d4\'d1\'c9 \'cc\'e6\'ed\'c9\par
 \cf1\'c7\'e1\'e3\'cf\'f8\'c9 : \cf2\f3 00:00:33.0\cf3\i\f4 .\v <\f1\ltrch PSI_END_OBJECT\f4\rtlch >\cf0\protect0\v0\f1\ltrch\par
```

as you can see, the only difference here are the 2 "protect" entries. Text wise they are exactly the same.

could this be a Microsoft bug or am I missing something? FYI we are on .NET framework 4.6.2, VS2015 Update3

Comment: I would have expected that any assignment to the Rtf property clears the undo/redo buffers, so that may have nothing to do with the content, but the fact that an assignment from code occurs?

Comment: thanks for the feedback. you might be correct, but what's the proper way to modify the RTF while having undo buffer properly maintained? In my case I need to mark a region "protected" so the Rtf will need to be changed...

Comment: documentation does not really address this, but [look here](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/82/generic-undoredo-stack-in-csharp): "Some operations require replacing the entire RTF content which clears the undo/redo stack. This was a problem". I would not go so far as to call it a bug though. this article may work for you (richtextbox inherits its undo/redu functionality from textbox): http://stackoverflow.com/q/34091319/1132334

Answer (score 2):

thanks to dlatikay, 
seems we cannot directly work with the Rtf assignment, doing so will cause the undo stack to be lost. the alternative way is to work with the Selected Rtf. the following code worked:

```
m_rtbText.SelectionStart = 0;
m_rtbText.SelectAll();
m_rtbText.SelectedRtf = sRtf;
```

this is basically a replace. the undo is retained.